# Increment version column on update

Tags: mysql, versioning, optimistic-locking

Must I increment a integer version column within an update (before) trigger?

Or is there something like `ON UPDATE AUTOINCREMENT` similar to `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` within table column declaration?

In SQL there is something like a `rowversion` column type for that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
delimiter //
create trigger inc_trg before update on your_table
for each row 
begin    
  set new.some_column = new.some_column + 1;
end
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thats the manual way, hoped for something similar to `rowversion` in SQL, but doubt there is one. Should the version not just be updated in case an values have changed?

Comment: note this isn't ideal as it will increase some_column even if the update doesn't change any values